# Why the truthmaker of OntoUML <<role>> must be a <<mediation>>?

Tags: ontology

The [thesis Ontological foundations for structural conceptual models](https://research.utwente.nl/en/publications/ontological-foundations-for-structural-conceptual-models) states that

> "Every relationally dependent entity (role and role mixins) must be
>   connected to an association end of a «mediation» relation."

(p.332). Why is a `<<member of>>` relation not enough to satisfy the relational dependance?

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a pattern of roles and role mixins for members of collectives, however, the membership to the collective has a truthmaker of its own.

If you only use the `«memberOf»` relation you'll be hiding the relator of "membership" that makes it true that "the endurant plays the role of a member of some collective". In order to have the complete pattern, you should capture the relator and the `«mediation»` relation between the role and the relator.

Notice that this is a pattern specific to the case involving roles (e.g., employees, students, band members). You can still have cases where there may not be a relator as the truthmaker of the `«memberOf»` relation.

Take, for instance, the collective `Forest` whose members are instances of `Tree`. In this case, you would not be interested in capturing the "membership" between trees and forests and that is OK as `Tree` should not be a role, but a category, kind or subkind. (hint: the truthmaker here is something more "tricky")